# awk - Print all lines containing the Max value found in the initial analysis

Tags: indexing, awk, max, line

I have the following AWK command.

```
(awk 'max=="" || $1 > max {max=$1; l=$0} END{ print l}' FS="|" $STAGE_FILE) < input.txt
```

My intention is to be able to extract print the line that has the Max value in column 1.
But considering the file input.txt below:

```
0.0008    6
9.0    10
9.0    19
0.7    33
```

the output I'm getting is

```
9.0    19
```

But what I wish would be

```
9.0    10
9.0    19
```

when I have two max values, in this case 9 (in the first column), the command only printed one of the rows and not all that have the Max value of 9.

What change in my code would allow you to print all lines with Max value of 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following.

```
awk '
{
  max=(max>$1?max:$1)
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  print arr[max]
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  max=(max>$1?max:$1)                 ##Creating max to get maximum value as $1 per line.
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] ORS:"")$0  ##Creating array arr with index of 1st field and keep adding its value to it with a new line.
}
END{                                  ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print arr[max]                      ##Printing arr with index of max here.
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `awk '{max=max>$1?max:$1;arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] ORS:"") $0} END{print arr[max]}'` as you have shown before the edition has worked correctly too.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, yeah, its just full form of code, I changed from one liner to full form for better understanding, cheers :)

Comment: See too my **edit update**, I'm sorry, I did not take into account the presence of decoration between the lines with numbers and this affects the need that gave rise to my question.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, Hello, IMHO, you would have opened a new question rather than editing old one. Now you had un-accpeted my working answer which was given as per your showed samples. Kindly don't do that, old answers shouldn't be edited since they may confuse readers/future readers. Request you to please revert question to OLD form and open a new question, thank you

Comment: I requested for user anubhaava to move his response to the new question I created here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960921/awk-print-all-lines-containing-the-max-value-found-in-the-initial-analysis-co

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm, Sure, thank you, I will also check your new question when I come online in morning.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '$1+0 != $1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $1) max=$1; next} $1 == max' file{,}

9.0    10
9.0    19
```

Note that we compute `max` in first phase and then in 2nd phase print all records that have `$1` same as `max` value.

PS: Your sample input is not pipe delimited as you are using in your question but if you have pipe delimited file then use:

```sh
awk -F'|' '$1+0 != $1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $1) max=$1; next} $1 == max' file{,}
```

Comment: See my **edit update**, I'm sorry, I did not take into account the presence of decoration between the lines with numbers and this affects the need that gave rise to my question.

Comment: I am checking the changes you did in relation to your last answer, but it worked correctly.

Comment: I would like to move your response to this a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66960921/awk-print-all-lines-containing-the-max-value-found-in-the-initial-analysis-co instead of editing the current issue.

Comment: Not to prejudice the response accepted previously from user ravindersingh13 the new question was created, please post your response there too, so that your response is taken advantage of.