# awk - Print all lines containing the Max value found in the initial analysis (Containing U+2500 Unicode Character between the lines)

Tags: indexing, awk, line

I have an issue that was answered here [awk - Print all lines containing the Max value found in the initial analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906638/awk-print-all-lines-containing-the-max-value-found-in-the-initial-analysis), but that now needs to be adapted to work when there is *U+2500 unicode character* between the lines.

The problem is as follows below, I have a new entry file as below:

```
0.0008    6
────────────
9.0    10
────────────
9.0    19
────────────
0.7    33
```

If I try to find the maximum value using the answers to [awk - Print all lines containing the Max value found in the initial analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906638/awk-print-all-lines-containing-the-max-value-found-in-the-initial-analysis), the output is always being as shown below:

```
──────
──────
──────
```

This is not the expected exit, But I should get something like:

```
9.0    10
9.0    19
```

**Note:** *This issue was created so as not to compromise the choice of the solution marked as "resolved" in the* [awk - Print all lines containing the Max value found in the initial analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906638/awk-print-all-lines-containing-the-max-value-found-in-the-initial-analysis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this 2 pass awk as well:

```sh
awk '$1+0 != $1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $1) max=$1; next} $1 == max' file{,}

9.0    10
9.0    19
```

We compute max in first phase and ignore all lines where `$1` is non-numeric, then in 2nd phase print all records that have `$1` same as `max` value.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
$1+0==$1{
  max=(max>$1?max:$1)
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  print arr[max]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
$1+0==$1{                                 ##Checking condition if 1st field is an integer.
  max=(max>$1?max:$1)                     ##Create max variable by having maximum value out of 1st field and max variable here.
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] ORS:"")$0      ##Create array with index of $1 and keep adding its value to it wit same index values.
}
END{                                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print arr[max]                          ##Printing array arr value with key of max here.
}
'  Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

NOTE: As per @karafka's suggestion adding `$1+0==$1` so that scientific notation, negative numbers are not missed

Comment: regex will still miss scientific notation, negative numbers, numbers starting with decimal point without leading zero etc.

Comment: @karakfa, thank you for letting know, if I change my answer now, it will become lie yours :)

Comment: Well, it was yours to begin with.  I'll delete mine once you change it.

Comment: @karakfa, Thank you for nice gesture :) that's so kind of your sir, if you would like to keep it please keep it I will delete mine no issues, since yours is already Good enough why to delete :)